# Check for hidden file/folder in a directory[VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to check if there is hidden file/folder in a directory/USB Drive. But i want to exclude system files such as thumbs.db, *.ini and System Volume Information. How to do this?

I tried

```
Dim exclude = {"thumbs.db", "*.ini", "System Volume Information"}
If (myDirectory.Attributes.ToString.Contains("Hidden").Except(exclude)) Then

''do something

else

''do something else

End If
```

But i got errors saying `except` is not a member of `boolean`.

Comment: @Timeout, i see. Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive procedure like this:

```
Module StartupModule

    Sub Main()
        Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Windows\Fonts")
        Dim paths As List(Of String) = FindHidden(di)

        For Each p In paths
            Console.WriteLine(p)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Private Function FindHidden(di As IO.DirectoryInfo) As List(Of String)
        Static paths As New List(Of String)

        If (di.Attributes And IO.FileAttributes.System) <> IO.FileAttributes.System Then
            If ((di.Attributes And IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) = IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) Then
                paths.Add(di.FullName)
            End If
        End If

        For Each f In di.GetFiles
            If ((f.Attributes And IO.FileAttributes.System) <> IO.FileAttributes.System) Then
                If ((f.Attributes And IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) = IO.FileAttributes.Hidden) Then
                    paths.Add(f.FullName)
                End If
            End If
        Next

        For Each d In di.GetDirectories
            FindHidden(d)
        Next

        Return paths
    End Function

End Module
```

You have to work it a bit because for read only files throws an exception (I'm at work so I don't have much time).

I think you get the meaning.

Comment: thanks for the answer @shadow. I'll let you know if it  works

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim fiArr As FileInfo() = myDirectory.GetFiles()
    Dim fri As FileInfo
    For Each fri In fiArr
        if (fri.Attributes.ToString.Contains("Hidden") and not fri.Name.Contains("thumbs.db")  and not fri.Name.Contains(".ini") and not fri.Name.Contains("System Volume Information"))
            ''do something
        else
            ''do something else
        End If
    Next fri

Dim dirArr As DirectoryInfo() = myDirectory.GetDirectories()
    Dim dinfo As DirectoryInfo
    For Each dinfo In dirArr
        if (dinfo.Attributes.ToString.Contains("Hidden") and not dinfo.Name.Contains("thumbs.db")  and not dinfo.Name.Contains(".ini") and not dinfo.Name.Contains("System Volume Information"))
            ''do something
        else
            ''do something else
        End If
    Next dinfo
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The codes are perfect. no error. but it return false while looking for hidden folder. even if there are hidden folder.

Comment: Updated solution to replicate file logic to folders.

Comment: it's great! But there's a little problem. It skipped one line of code.`If (dinfo.Attributes.ToString.Contains("Hidden") And Not dinfo.Name.Contains("thumbs.db") And Not dinfo.Name.Contains(".ini") And Not dinfo.Name.Contains("System Volume Information")) Then
                DriveClean = False
                unhide.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(232, 17, 35)
            Else
                unhide.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 163, 2)
            End If
        Next dinfo` It doesn't change the color to red when the DriveClean is false.

Comment: Where is 'DriveClean' in your question? My solution was for your question.  To add an additional condition, just add ' and DriveClean = False' to the if statement.